# Having trouble with mismatched types

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on some coding for work and running into some trouble. Fairly new to coding and some help would be great. I am getting an error run-time error '13' mismatched type at the eqp, si, fdp, seat, and leg areas. On my other macro it works perfectly fine and the data is grabbing is numbers. It is probably something minor if need more of the code please let me know will need to redact parts due to nature of job.

```
Dim rap As Variant
Dim fdp As Variant
Dim cfdp As Variant
Dim si As Variant
Dim seat As Variant
Dim eqp As Variant
Dim leg As Variant
Dim result As String

Base = Range("a2:a500000")
eqp = Range("b2:b500000").Value '' identify equipment
si = Range("c2:c500000").Value '' Time at which the sequence and fdp start
fdp = Range("d2:d500000").Value '' fdp for the first day of the sequence
seat = Range("e2:e500000").Value '' number of seat position
leg = Range("f2:f500000").Value '' fdp per far part 117 table b chart




If seat = "3" Or "4" Then
    If eqp = "757" Then
        If si >= 0 Then
            If si <= 559 Then
                If seat = 3 Then
                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("h18").Value
                ElseIf seat = 4 Then
                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("g18").Value
                End If



            ElseIf si >= 600 Then
                If si <= 659 Then
                    If seat = 3 Then
                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("f19").Value
                    ElseIf seat = 4 Then
                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("g19").Value
                    End If



                ElseIf si >= 700 Then
                    If si <= 1259 Then
                        If seat = 3 Then
                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("f20").Value
                        ElseIf seat = 4 Then
                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("g20").Value

                        End If



                    ElseIf si >= 1300 Then
                        If si <= 1659 Then
                            If seat = 3 Then
                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("f21").Value
                            ElseIf seat = 4 Then
                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("g21").Value
                            End If



                        ElseIf si >= 1700 Then
                            If si <= 2359 Then
                                If seat = 3 Then
                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("f22").Value
                                ElseIf seat = 4 Then
                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("g22").Value
                                End If



                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If


    ElseIf eqp = "330" Or "767" Then
        If si >= 0 Then
            If si <= 559 Then
                If seat = 3 Then
                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("d18").Value
                ElseIf seat = 4 Then
                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("e18").Value
                End If



            ElseIf si >= 600 Then
                If si <= 659 Then
                    If seat = 3 Then
                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("d19").Value
                    ElseIf seat = 4 Then
                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("e19").Value
                    End If



                ElseIf si >= 700 Then
                    If si <= 1259 Then
                        If seat = 3 Then
                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("d20").Value
                        ElseIf seat = 4 Then
                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("e20").Value
                        End If



                    ElseIf si >= 1300 Then
                        If si <= 1659 Then
                            If seat = 3 Then
                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("d21").Value
                            ElseIf seat = 4 Then
                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("e21").Value
                            End If



                        ElseIf si >= 1700 Then
                            If si <= 2359 Then
                                If seat = 3 Then
                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("d22").Value
                                ElseIf seat = 4 Then
                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("e22").Value
                                End If

                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If


    ElseIf eqp = "777" Or "787" Then
        If si >= 0 Then
            If si <= 559 Then
                If seat = 3 Then
                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("b18").Value
                ElseIf seat = 4 Then
                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("c18").Value
                End If



            ElseIf si >= 600 Then
                If si <= 659 Then
                    If seat = 3 Then
                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("b19").Value
                    ElseIf seat = 4 Then
                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("c19").Value
                    End If



                ElseIf si >= 700 Then
                    If si <= 1259 Then
                        If seat = 3 Then
                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("b20").Value
                        ElseIf seat = 4 Then
                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("c20").Value
                        End If



                    ElseIf si >= 1300 Then
                        If si <= 1659 Then
                            If seat = 3 Then
                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("b21").Value
                            ElseIf seat = 4 Then
                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("c21").Value
                            End If



                        ElseIf si >= 1700 Then
                            If si <= 2359 Then
                                If seat = 3 Then
                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("b22").Value
                                ElseIf seat = 4 Then
                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("c22").Value
                                End If

                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If

    End If


    If seat = "2" Then
        If si >= 0 Then
            If si <= 359 Then
                If leg = "1" Then
                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("b5").Value
                ElseIf leg = "2" Then
                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("c5").Value
                ElseIf leg = "3" Then
                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("d5").Value
                ElseIf leg = "4" Then
                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("e5").Value
                ElseIf leg = "5" Then
                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("f5").Value
                ElseIf leg = "6" Then
                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("g5").Value
                ElseIf leg = "7" Then
                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("h5").Value
                End If




            ElseIf si >= 400 Then
                If si <= 459 Then
                    If leg = "1" Then
                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("b6").Value
                    ElseIf leg = "2" Then
                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("c6").Value
                    ElseIf leg = "3" Then
                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("d6").Value
                    ElseIf leg = "4" Then
                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("e6").Value
                    ElseIf leg = "5" Then
                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("f6").Value
                    ElseIf leg = "6" Then
                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("g6").Value
                    ElseIf leg = "7" Then
                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("h6").Value
                    End If



                ElseIf si >= 500 Then
                    If si <= 559 Then
                        If leg = "1" Then
                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("b7").Value
                        ElseIf leg = "2" Then
                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("c7").Value
                        ElseIf leg = "3" Then
                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("d7").Value
                        ElseIf leg = "4" Then
                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("e7").Value
                        ElseIf leg = "5" Then
                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("f7").Value
                        ElseIf leg = "6" Then
                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("g7").Value
                        ElseIf leg = "7" Then
                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("h7").Value
                        End If



                    ElseIf si >= 600 Then
                        If si <= 659 Then
                            If leg = "1" Then
                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("b8").Value
                            ElseIf leg = "2" Then
                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("c8").Value
                            ElseIf leg = "3" Then
                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("d8").Value
                            ElseIf leg = "4" Then
                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("e8").Value
                            ElseIf leg = "5" Then
                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("f8").Value
                            ElseIf leg = "6" Then
                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("g8").Value
                            ElseIf leg = "7" Then
                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("h8").Value
                            End If



                        ElseIf si >= 700 Then
                            If si <= 1159 Then
                                If leg = "1" Then
                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("b9").Value
                                ElseIf leg = "2" Then
                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("c9").Value
                                ElseIf leg = "3" Then
                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("d9").Value
                                ElseIf leg = "4" Then
                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("e9").Value
                                ElseIf leg = "5" Then
                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("f9").Value
                                ElseIf leg = "6" Then
                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("g9").Value
                                ElseIf leg = "7" Then
                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("h9").Value
                                End If



                            ElseIf si >= 1200 Then
                                If si <= 1259 Then
                                    If leg = "1" Then
                                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("b10").Value
                                    ElseIf leg = "2" Then
                                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("c10").Value
                                    ElseIf leg = "3" Then
                                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("d10").Value
                                    ElseIf leg = "4" Then
                                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("e10").Value
                                    ElseIf leg = "5" Then
                                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("f10").Value
                                    ElseIf leg = "6" Then
                                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("g10").Value
                                    ElseIf leg = "7" Then
                                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("h10").Value
                                    End If


                                ElseIf si >= 1300 Then
                                    If si <= 1659 Then
                                        If leg = "1" Then
                                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("b11").Value
                                        ElseIf leg = "2" Then
                                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("c11").Value
                                        ElseIf leg = "3" Then
                                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("d11").Value
                                        ElseIf leg = "4" Then
                                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("e11").Value
                                        ElseIf leg = "5" Then
                                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("f11").Value
                                        ElseIf leg = "6" Then
                                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("g11").Value
                                        ElseIf leg = "7" Then
                                            cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("h11").Value
                                        End If



                                    ElseIf si >= 1700 Then
                                        If si <= 2159 Then
                                            If leg = "1" Then
                                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("b12").Value
                                            ElseIf leg = "2" Then
                                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("c12").Value
                                            ElseIf leg = "3" Then
                                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("d12").Value
                                            ElseIf leg = "4" Then
                                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("e12").Value
                                            ElseIf leg = "5" Then
                                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("f12").Value
                                            ElseIf leg = "6" Then
                                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("g12").Value
                                            ElseIf leg = "7" Then
                                                cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("h12").Value
                                            End If



                                        ElseIf si >= 2200 Then
                                            If si <= 2259 Then
                                                If leg = " 1" Then
                                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("b13").Value
                                                ElseIf leg = "2" Then
                                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("c13").Value
                                                ElseIf leg = "3" Then
                                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("d13").Value
                                                ElseIf leg = "4" Then
                                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("e13").Value
                                                ElseIf leg = "5" Then
                                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("f13").Value
                                                ElseIf leg = "6" Then
                                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("g13").Value
                                                ElseIf leg = "7" Then
                                                    cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("h13").Value
                                                End If



                                            ElseIf si >= 2300 Then
                                                If si <= 2359 Then
                                                    If leg = "1" Then
                                                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("b14").Value
                                                    ElseIf leg = "2" Then
                                                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("c14").Value
                                                    ElseIf leg = "3" Then
                                                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("d14").Value
                                                    ElseIf leg = "4" Then
                                                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("e14").Value
                                                    ElseIf leg = "5" Then
                                                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("f14").Value
                                                    ElseIf leg = "6" Then
                                                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("g14").Value
                                                    ElseIf leg = "7" Then
                                                        cfdp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAR117Chart").Range("h14").Value
                                                    End If

                                                End If
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If



        End If

    End If
End If




If Base = "LGA" Or "LAX" Then

    If 200 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((200 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "0200"
        End If
    ElseIf 300 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((400 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "0400"
        End If
    ElseIf 400 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((400 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "0400"
        End If
    ElseIf 500 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((500 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "0500"
        End If
    ElseIf 600 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((600 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "0600"
        End If
    ElseIf 700 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((700 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "0700"
        End If
    ElseIf 800 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((800 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "0800"
        End If
    ElseIf 900 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((900 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "0900"
        End If
    ElseIf 1000 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((1000 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1000"
        End If
    ElseIf 1100 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs(((1100 - si)) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1100"
        End If
    ElseIf 1200 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((1200 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1200"
        End If
    ElseIf 1400 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((1400 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1400"
        End If
    ElseIf 1400 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((1400 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1400"
        End If
    ElseIf 1500 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((1500 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1500"
        End If
    ElseIf 1600 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((1600 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1600"
        End If
    ElseIf 1700 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((1700 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1700"
        End If
    ElseIf 1800 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((1800 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1800"
        End If
    ElseIf 1900 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((1900 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1900"
        End If
    ElseIf 2000 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((2000 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "2000"
        End If
    ElseIf 2100 < Abs(si - 400) Then
        If fdp < Abs((2100 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "2100"
        End If

    ElseIf 200 < Abs(Abs(si - 300)) Then
        If fdp < Abs((200 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "0200"
        End If

    ElseIf 300 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs((300 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "0300"
        End If

    ElseIf 400 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs((400 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "0400"
        End If

    ElseIf 500 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs((500 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "0500"
        End If

    ElseIf 600 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs((600 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "0600"
        End If

    ElseIf 700 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs((700 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "0700"
        End If

    ElseIf 800 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs((800 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "0800"
        End If

    ElseIf 900 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs((900 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "0900"
        End If

    ElseIf 1000 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs((1000 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1000"
        End If

    ElseIf 1100 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs(((1100 - si)) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1100"
        End If

    ElseIf 1200 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs((1200 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1200"
        End If

    ElseIf 1300 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs((1300 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1300"
        End If

    ElseIf 1400 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs((1400 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1400"
        End If

    ElseIf 1500 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs((1500 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1500"
        End If

    ElseIf 1600 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs((1600 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1600"
        End If

    ElseIf 1700 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs((1700 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1700"
        End If

    ElseIf 1800 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs((1800 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1800"
        End If

    ElseIf 1900 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs((1900 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "1900"
        End If

    ElseIf 2000 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs((2000 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "2000"
        End If

    ElseIf 2100 < Abs(si - 300) Then
        If fdp < Abs((2100 - si) - cfdp) Then
            result = "2100"
        End If

        Range("j2:j500000").Value = result

    End If
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: The `.Value` of a multi-cell `Range` is a 2D Variant array. How do you plan to use these ranges?

Comment: Are you sure you want integers. They are 16 bit integers so +/- 32K only.

Comment: Take a look at [this link](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/#Reading_from_a_Range_of_Cells_to_an_Array) to understand what your code is doing (so you can decide if that is your intention).

Comment: @BigBen yes my previous data complies filling up a lot of lines so I was trying to set more than that because the new data will be 2-4 times as much.

Comment: @Mark I'm fairly new and learning by looking at online blogs and tutorials to figure the coding out. If there is something else I should use instead of integers please let me know.

Comment: What are you actually doing with these ranges? Can  you share more of your code?

Comment: @RobertLewis Change the declarations to `Variant` and it will fill them as variant arrays that you can then loop through.

Comment: In VBA and VB6 (which uses the VBA language) an integer is a Windows 3.1 integer. This is because VB4 had 16 and 32 bit compile options. So your 16 bit code will compile and work in 32 bit Windows. In VB we call 32 bit integers a `long` (+/- 2 billion odd).

Comment: @ScottCraner that worked but now I'm getting it when I start my if statements.

Comment: @BigBen I posted more of the code

Comment: You need a loop.

Comment: You cannot equate a single value to an array of values.  As @BigBen stated you will need to loop through the arrays.

Comment: I will take a look at how to build loops and rework the code thanks for the help everyone

Comment: `If eqp = "777" Or "787" Then` should be `If eqp = "777" Or eqp = "787" Then`   In general this type of criteria-checking typically works better if you can code the checks into one or more worksheet tables and use those to drive your code.